# Progress Function Called Too Often Using pycurl For FTP Upload

Tags: python, upload, ftp, progress, pycurl

I'm on Ubuntu 12.0.4 with pycurl version 7.19 and libcurl3 version 7.22 (pycurl and libcurl both installed directly from Ubuntu repositories with apt-get). My code to upload a file is ("self" is a wrapper object of mine):

```
self.curlTransfer = pycurl.Curl()
self.curlTransfer.setopt(pycurl.UPLOAD, 1)
self.curlTransfer.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, '%s:%s'%(str(self.userName), str(self.password)))
self.curlTransfer.setopt(pycurl.NOPROGRESS, 0)
self.curlTransfer.setopt(pycurl.PROGRESSFUNCTION, self.__UpdateFileTransferProgress)
f = open(fileName, 'rb')
self.curlTransfer.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'ftp://' + self.ipAddress + self.path + destination)
self.curlTransfer.setopt(pycurl.INFILESIZE_LARGE, os.path.getsize(fileName))
self.curlTransfer.setopt(pycurl.READFUNCTION, f.read)
self.curlTransfer.perform()
```

My callback function "__UpdateFileTransferProgress" gets called thousands of times per second to the point where the transfer is ~3X slower than if I turn off the progress callback. I have searched far and wide to resolve this and the only relevant thing I have found is [this curl bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/1238/). It sounds like the bug may have been patched, but it's unclear if the patch has made it into my version (or if this is a different issue entirely).

Has anyone come across this? I looked into updating to the latest libcurl/pycurl versions manually, but trying to work through the dependencies deterred me. I really like the performance of pycurl compared to ftplib (when the progress callback is disabled), but I need the callback function to track the transfer progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SEE EDIT FOR CLEANER SOLUTION!

I bit the bullet and downloaded the latest source for libcurl and pycurl (was actually pretty easy to build/install). This improved the situation, as the progress function is now only called hundreds of times per second instead of thousands, but there is still a very noticeable performance hit when using the progress callback. To circumvent this, I setup the transfer like this:

```
# Set transfer parameters.
self.curlTransfer.fp = open(fileName, 'rb')
self.curlTransfer.fileSize = os.path.getsize(fileName)
self.curlTransfer.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'ftp://' + self.ipAddress + self.path + destination)
self.curlTransfer.setopt(pycurl.INFILESIZE_LARGE, self.curlTransfer.fileSize)
self.curlTransfer.setopt(pycurl.READDATA, self.curlTransfer.fp)

# Store file.
self.curlTransfer.perform()
```

And then if I want to get the progress in another thread:

```
def GetDataTransferred(self):
"""
Gets the amount of data transferred for the current file transfer.

@return Amount of data transferred (MB).
"""
try:

    # Try/except in case file is closed.
    try:
        return (float(self.curlTransfer.fp.tell())/float(myConstants.MB))
    except:
        if(self.curlTransfer.fileSize):
            return self.curlTransfer.fileSize

    return 0

except:
    Warning("Unable to get the amount of data transferred.")
    return 0
```

Basically I cheat and use the file pointer "tell" to see where pycurl is in the transfer.

Edit/Solved: I ended up fixing the bug in libcurl myself by modifying /lib/progress.c as shown in the bug report thread in my OP ([Imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVxpR.png)). It sounds like they committed the fix in their trunk source code, but it's not included in their latest release (7.37.1). The reason I ended up going this route is because the cleanest way to stop a transfer is to return nonzero from the progress function. You can return nonzero from your pycurl.READFUNCTION to stop a transfer, but with an FTP upload, that function gets called once per block (~16KB) and is very slow (use pycurl.READDATA instead and provide a file pointer). Now I can cleanly stop a transfer, use their intended progress update method, and keep the high performance of libcurl.